# Is there a gradle fix for "Could not determine artifacts for (library from Jitpack)"?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

When syncing dependencies in android studio, starting recently, gradle began throwing this error on repositories loaded from Jitpack. This is an example, after invalidating cache and reloading, this is just the first Jitpack library in my dependency list -

```
Could not determine artifacts for com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:v1.2.0: 
Skipped due to earlier error
```

I attempted to update the version of the libraries, attempted to first revert, then update my versions of gradle, and the gradle build tools. I have updated android studio and the android build tools. Invalidated cache, and deleted the contents of the build folder. I ran the gradle commands from the terminal with stacktrace enabled to determine what the "earlier error" might have been but the only error listed is for the artifact not being found.

Top level build file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle seems to have been throwing the error on a random library from Jitpack, but the error seems to have come from a different repository that was supposed to be referencing mavenCentral. I noticed it attempting multiple downloads of the library in the logs and found a way to change the way it was referenced to be more definitive and that seems to have fixed my problem.

Comment: Could you share details of your solution? I'm facing a similar issue. Were you specifying transitive dependencies within your app's `build.gradle`?